# Can't find variable: webpackJsonp

Tags: webpack

I'm occasional getting this error and can't work out why. My vendor bundle is before my main bundle so there is no reason for this error to occur and I can't ever get the error.

The only thing I've thought of is my site uses http2 so could this cause script to be loaded out of order?

Comment: I'm also seeing this error coming up in my error logging, but can't reproduce it.

Comment: see the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988166/ionic-2-referenceerror-webpackjsonp-is-not-defined it help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2: ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988166/ionic-2-referenceerror-webpackjsonp-is-not-defined)